# The number of intersection points between a trivial loop and a meridian in the torus

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

Let A and B be two closed curves intersect on the torus transversally at a point, the intersection index of the crossing point is defined to be positive if the tangent vectors to A and B form an oriented basis for the tangent plane of the torus and negative otherwise. Then the intersection number of A and B is the sum of the signs over all intersection points between A and B. The intersection number of two classes in the homology is the minimum intersection number over all representatives of the two classes.

Suppose A is a trivial loop ( boundary of a disk) in the torus and B is a meridian of the torus. Suppose also that A and B intersect at two crossing points, then what is the intersection number of A and B in this case? Can we have such a case? I am confusing because the orientation of basis of tangent vectors is preserved along the trivial loop A in the torus, so we can not have positive and negative orientations at the transversal intersection points, is this true? Any guidance or comments is highly appreciated

thank you in advance

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection number of $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ is equal to the intersection number of their respective inclusion maps. However the inclusion map corresponding to $C_{1}$ is homotopic to the constant map. Thus, the intersection number has to be zero.

Comment: The intersection number is zero, yes. But does this mean the points of intersection are zero ? I mean they can not intersect.

Comment: They can, but the point is one of them can always be smoothly pulled out so that they no longer intersect.

Comment: Sorry I am using another definition of the intersection number, two loops intersect at point, we say that the intersection point is positive if the tangent vectors to the two loops form an oriented basis for the tangent plane of the torus and otherwise negative, then the intersection number is defined to be the sum of all signs over all crossing of the two loops. In this sense, I think the answer of my question is that if one of the loops is trivial, then the other one must not intersect it at all, right?

Comment: @user113715, Yes.

Comment: @user113715 this is not correct. There can be intersections, its just that one will have a negative sign, while the other will have a positive sign, hence they add up to zero. But they can definitely intersect.

Answer (score 1):

[**Recall**](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Patrias.pdf#3) that the *[geometric] intersection number* of homotopy classes for loops $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is defined as $\min|a \cap b|$ across *all* representatives $a \in \alpha$ and $b \in \beta$.

For the scenario you've introduced, clearly there are representatives for which the minimum of $0$ is attained. So, the issue is not whether an individual representation contains intersections, but rather what the minimum is across *all* representatives. As a bit of overkill, here are sample pictures:

[image]

On the other hand, consider two curves on the torus -- one meridian, one longitudinal -- and you will find that any representatives from the corresponding homotopy classes leads to an intersection.

Comment: Ok, if we say the point $C_1$ is contained in the other curve $C_2$ for example, then what is the intersection between these representatives of the trivial loop and any other loop. Of course this must be greater than or equal to the intersection number